# ASP.NET Core 6: How to issue authentication tokens compatible with old ASP.NET WebAPI apps (.NET Framework 4.7)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, bearer-token, openiddict

I'll try to describe problem as simple as possible.

Here is my current situation: I have 2 ASP.NET Web API apps. First app issues OAuth access tokens in exchange on user's login and password, let's call this app `Issuer`. The second app has several controllers, protected with `[Authorize]` attributes, it allows access to this controllers only for authorized users, who supplied valid access tokens. Let's call this app `Consumer`.

For now both web apps are hosted on Windows and running on .NET Framework 4.7. Both apps use OWIN and share same machine key - latter is necessary for `Consumer` app to be able to accept tokens issued by `Issuer` app.

Here are some details on the `Issuer` app.

OWIN startup class:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        try
        {          
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();

            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            ConfigureAuth(app);

            app.UseCors(...);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}

public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ...
    var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        Provider = new CustomProvider(...)
    };
    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(oAuthServerOptions);
}
```

`CustomProvider` class inherits from `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` and contains some logic.

`web.config` part:

```
...
<system.web>
   <machineKey configSource="....config" />
</system.web>
...
```

And here are some details of the `Consumer` app.

OWIN startup class:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        try
        {          
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();

            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            ConfigureAuth(app);

            app.UseCors(...);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}

public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ...        
    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions());
}
```

`Web.config` part is completely same as in the `Issuer` app.

So this is what I have.

And this is what I'm trying to achieve: I need to port Issuer app to .NET 6 and it will run on Linux. But ported app must produce authorization tokens which will be accepted by `Consumer` app. The `Consumer` app can not be ported to .NET 6 for now for various reasons.

So I'm trying to setup and use OpenIddict for issuing tokens. But I can't configure OpenIddict to produce tokens compatible with the existing `Consumer` app.

What I have in ported `Issuer` app:

```
protected override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...
   services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(io =>
                                              {
                                                  ...
                                              })
            .AddUserStore<...>()
            .AddUserManager<...>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.AddOpenIddict()
            .AddServer(o =>
                       {
                           o.UseDataProtection()
                            .Configure(c => c.DataProtectionProvider = 
                                                new MachineKeyDataProtector("validation key from machine key config file",
                                                                            "decryption key"));
                           o.SetTokenEndpointUris("...");
                           o.SetAccessTokenLifetime(...)
                           o.DisableAccessTokenEncryption();

                           o.AllowPasswordFlow();
                           o.AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

                           o.UseAspNetCore()
                            .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough();

                           o.AddEphemeralEncryptionKey()
                            .AddEphemeralSigningKey();

                           o.EnableDegradedMode();

                           o.AddEventHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.ValidateTokenRequestContext>(c => c.UseInlineHandler((context) =>
                                                                                                                         {
                                                                                                                             return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
                                                                                                                         }));
                       })

}
```

I'm using `MachineKeyDataProtector` class from the [AspNetTicketBridge NuGet package](https://github.com/dmarlow/AspNetTicketBridge/blob/master/src/MachineKeyDataProtector.cs)

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(options =>
        {
            options.MapControllers();
            options.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });
}
```

As a result tokens are issued but they are not accepted by the `Consumer` app - it returns an "401 Unauthorized" error.

What have I done wrong or missed? Or is there any simpler approach?

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated :) Many thanks.

Comment: I try to refer to the documents but did not get the exact information regarding the .NetCore 6.0. Further, I found this [helpful question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d1543d05-c5c4-43f2-a43c-cdfad2d40f89/how-to-share-bearer-tokens-between-aspnet-4x-and-aspnet-5-applications?forum=aspdotnetcore). You could refer to the accepted answer may help you get some hints.